# How is it that a single transmission line can be modeled by a two port network?

Tags: power

I am studying electric power distribution. I've read in Kirtley's *Electric Power Principles* (2010) that a transmission line can be modeled by the 'pi' model. Which is a two port network with series conductance and parallel capacitance. But a transmission line (single phase) is just one cable, with current going through it. How can this be modeled by a two port network?

Thanks.

Comment: Return channel is through the ground?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Emili Pisanty - Also physicists, perhaps with exception of unworldly theorists,  should understand  transmission lines and two-port networks. And for experimentalists, it's quite often a necessity!

Comment: Now, @freecharly, we have all seen people taking data with little understanding of the electronics! (Sad, but true).

Comment: As for the question, how many ports do you think are needed to describe the transmission line as a lumped element? I see _in_ and _out_, which means two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A power transmission line is, indeed, one cable, but the current that flows into the cable has a return path via the ground. Thus you have two terminals (first port) at the power station and two terminals (second port) where the load is located. Therefore you can consider the power transmission line as a two-port network.

Comment: Since there is a current, I assume the line is in a circuit. On both ends is a transformer. One terminal of each transformer is connected to the transmission line and the other terminal of each is connect to the ground at each respective location. That is what I gather from the answer above. If I understood that correctly, I don't see how the earth closes the circuit to allow the current to flow in the transmission line.

Comment: @JMcB - The ground serves as the second conductor of the transmission line. You can easily check that at you local power outlet. If you stand with bare (wet) feet on the not insulating ground (like stone or tile), and you touch only one  terminal with your finger (you have to try which is the not grounded one), you will feel a shock. This is because the ground serves as the conductor back to the grid voltage supply. (Please, don't really try to do this, it is dangerous!)